# Non toxic glowing food or drink

Tags: cake, drinks, safety

Is there a way to make a chemiluminescencent reaction that is safe for consumption by humans?

That is to say is it possible to make an item of food or drink that glows and is at worst non toxic? There are quite a few references available for general reactions of this kind (e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemiluminescence)) but none of them are obviously safe to consume. It seems if I could find a way to make such things safe to consume then it would open the door to awesome punch and/or cake recipes.

Comment: Have you seen [this Q/A](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/85237/halloween-special-glow-in-the-dark-food?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C50.9901)?

Comment: No, I didn't see that one when searching at all

Comment: It's possible that there are more things available now, but if you're willing to use blacklight, see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/28495/67